# Пустые миграции при запуске alembic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

alembic генерирует пустые миграции

Вот файл env.py:

```
import os
import sys
from logging.config import fileConfig
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'src'))


from core.database import Base, SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
from core.config import DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_USER

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config


section = config.config_ini_section
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_HOST", DB_HOST)
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_PORT", DB_PORT)
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_USER", DB_USER)
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_NAME", DB_NAME)
config.set_section_option(section, "DB_PASS", DB_PASS)
# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    # url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    url = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},

    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    # configuration = config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
    # configuration['sqlalchemy.url'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
    # connectable = engine_from_config(
    #     configuration,
    #     prefix="sqlalchemy.",
    #     poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    # )
    # configuration = config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
    # configuration['sqlalchemy.url'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

И вот файл alembic.ini:

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = migrations

include_schemas = True
compare_type = True
# template used to generate migration files
# file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s
file_template = %%(year)d-%%(month).2d-%%(day).2d_%%(slug)s
# sys.path path, will be prepended to sys.path if present.
# defaults to the current working directory.
prepend_sys_path = .

# timezone to use when rendering the date within the migration file
# as well as the filename.
# If specified, requires the python-dateutil library that can be
# installed by adding `alembic[tz]` to the pip requirements
# string value is passed to dateutil.tz.gettz()
# leave blank for localtime
# timezone =

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
# truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; This defaults
# to migrations/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path.
# The path separator used here should be the separator specified by "version_path_separator"
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar:%(here)s/bat:migrations/versions

# version path separator; As mentioned above, this is the character used to split
# version_locations. Valid values are:
#
# version_path_separator = :
# version_path_separator = ;
# version_path_separator = space
version_path_separator = os  # default: use os.pathsep

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

# sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:pass@localhost/dbname
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://%(DB_USER)s:%(DB_PASS)s@%(DB_HOST)s:%(DB_PORT)s/%(DB_NAME)s

[post_write_hooks]
# post_write_hooks defines scripts or Python functions that are run
# on newly generated revision scripts.  See the documentation for further
# detail and examples

# format using "black" - use the console_scripts runner, against the "black" entrypoint
# hooks = black
# black.type = console_scripts
# black.entrypoint = black
# black.options = -l 79 REVISION_SCRIPT_FILENAME

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

https://github.com/efir-it/store-v2.git - вот репозиторий
Я использовал декларативный подход sqlalchey к написанию объектов бд, т. к. он считается современным, но при таком подходе при создании модели не передается metadata. В других репозиториях видел в target_metadata просто передает Base.metadata. Я сделал также, но нечего не поменялось. Также, читал, что надо включить параметры

```
include_schemas = True
compare_type = True
```

Для создания миграций я использовал команду `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "create db"` и после -  `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "create db"`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но тоже безрезультатно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема. Я сделал импорт не из файла, где я инициализировал переменную Base = declarative_base(), а из того файла, где я описываю модели. То есть как бы прокидываю Base через файлы, тогда Alembic видит модели. Если файлов с моделями несколько, то надо так же по цепочке передавать Base.

Answer (score 0):

Алембик не видит ваши модели. Скорее всего это связано с импортами. До того момента как алембик начнёт искать таблицы связанные с базовым классом они (таблицы) должны уже быть проинициализированы. В вашей ситуации решение может быть следующим :  в **init**.py импортировать всё базовые классы с помощью которых вы создавали таблицы. Тоесть если у вас есть два файла в которых определены модели, и они  наследуются от одной BaseModel то в **init**.py который находится на одном уровне с файлом где определена BaseModel прописываете:

```
from file1 import BaseModel
from file2 import BaseModel
```

и всё должно работать